# display parameter value within formula crystal reports

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, report, formula

I'm using Crystal Reports 14.

I have a formula which based on two parameters (from month, to month) display different text AND different parameters

My code is as follows

```
IF ({parameter1}) = 1 AND ({parameter 2})=14
THEN 'text {?parameter3} text'
```

My problem is that instead of the value of paramter3, CR display the name of the parameter in the report.

Any ideas how to display parameter value within formula and not the name?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to note is to select the value of the parameter before running the report then you can get the value.

```
IF ({parameter1}) = 1 AND ({parameter 2})=14
THEN 'text' & {?parameter3} & 'text'
```